# How to loop over piped lines and use lines as variable in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, pipe

When my server says `*** System restart required ***` I want to know whether there are any highly urgent matters that need updated. For this I can do the following in order:

```
cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
# Which outputs something like:
#    linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic
#    linux-base
#    dbus

aptitude changelog <package-name> | grep urgency=high
# If there is no output, there is no patch waiting with a high urgency
```

I now want to combine these two commands into one so that it automatically loops over de output of the first command, and uses that line as `<package-name>`.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
xargs aptitude changelog < /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs | grep ...
```